# visual studio doesn't build application before running it

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2012

I have a visual studio application that when I click on debug, even when I made some changes to it, it is not build the exe and I need to do it manually by clicking on build from menu. How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check configuration manager (right click on the solution node) and verify that the project is set to be built for the current configuration. If the project is not selected to build, the last built version will run instead.